# Merge Columns into One Column Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, merge

I have the following script and tables where upon running the script produces the output for LOG_ID,  YEAR, WA.SUB_DIVISION, AI.SUB_DIVISION, EA.SUB_DIVISION, FI.SUB_DIVISION

Is it possible to Merge four columns into one column 
WA.SUB_DIVISION, AI.SUB_DIVISION, EA.SUB_DIVISION, FI.SUB_DIVISION   into SUB_DIVISION     a single column

Not sure how to proceed.

I have created a sample sql fiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3c4abb924462dcf5e5f8b0f91019b6b6

```
       select  distinct  L.LOG_ID, 
        FC.LOG_YR as YEAR, 
        WA.SUB_DIVISION, 
        AI.SUB_DIVISION AS SUB_DIV, 
        EA.SUB_DIVISION AS SUB_DIV3, 
        FI.SUB_DIVISION AS SUB_DIV4
            FROM FINAL_CALENDAR FC
                 JOIN LOG L
                    ON TO_DATE (  TO_CHAR (L.LOG_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') = FC.CAL_DATE

                 LEFT OUTER JOIN LOG_WATER WA
                    ON WA.LOG_ID = L.LOG_ID
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN LOG_AIR AI
                    ON AI.LOG_ID = L.LOG_ID
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN LOG_EARTH EA
                    ON EA.LOG_ID = L.LOG_ID              
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN LOG_FIRE FI
                    ON FI.LOG_ID = L.LOG_ID
```

**Actual Output / ISSUE / Existing Output**

```
LOG_ID  YEAR  SUB_DIVISION     SUB_DIV    SUB_DIV3    SUB_DIV4

990741  2020    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
990742  2020    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
991122  2020    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
991123  2020    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
994461  2020    NULL    4       NULL    NULL
994468  2020    NULL    2       NULL    NULL
994466  2020    NULL    2       NULL    NULL
994480  2020    8       NULL    NULL    NULL
994479  2020    8       NULL    NULL    NULL
994476  2020    6       NULL    NULL    NULL
994478  2020    6       NULL    NULL    NULL
994440  2020    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
994432  2020    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
994450  2020    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
994154  2020    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

**Required / Desired Output**

```
LOG_ID   YEAR  SUB_DIVISION     DISPLAY_NAME

990741  2020    NULL            NULL
990742  2020    NULL            NULL   
991122  2020    NULL            NULL
991123  2020    NULL            NULL
994461  2020    4               Triangle       
994468  2020    2               Circle  
994466  2020    2               Circle    
994480  2020    8               Rhombus   
994479  2020    8               Rhombus
994476  2020    6               Dot    
994478  2020    6               Dot
994440  2020    NULL            NULL
994432  2020    NULL            NULL
994450  2020    NULL            NULL
994154  2020    NULL            NULL
```

Table LOG;

```
LOG_ID,         LOG_DATE,           
990741,         to_date('21-JAN-20','DD-MON-RR')
990742                  21-JAN-20                
991122                  24-JAN-20                
991123                  25-JAN-20                
994461                  25-JAN-20
994468                  25-JAN-20
994466                  25-JAN-20
994480                  25-JAN-20
994479                  25-JAN-20
994476                  25-JAN-20
994478                  25-JAN-20
994440                  25-JAN-20
994432                  25-JAN-20
994450                  25-JAN-20
994154                  25-JAN-20
```

TABLE   FINAL_CALENDAR;

```
CAL_DATE    CAL_MONTH           LOG_YR
21-JAN-20   1                   2020
21-JAN-20   1                   2020
24-JAN-20   1                   2020
25-JAN-20   1                   2020               
25-JAN-20   1                   2020 
25-JAN-20   1                   2020 
25-JAN-20   1                   2020               
25-JAN-20   1                   2020 
25-JAN-20   1                   2020 
25-JAN-20   1                   2020               
25-JAN-20   1                   2020 
25-JAN-20   1                   2020 
25-JAN-20   1                   2020               
25-JAN-20   1                   2020 
25-JAN-20   1                   2020
```

TABLE   LOG_AIR;

```
ID      LOG_ID  SUB_DIVISION
134     994468  2
132     994461  4
133     994466  2
```

TABLE LOG_WATER;

```
ID      LOG_ID  SUB_DIVISION
9345    994480  8
9344    994479  8
9342    994476  6
9343    994478  6
```

TABLE LOG_EARTH;

```
ID      LOG_ID          SUB_DIVISION
0118    994440          null
0117    994432          null
```

TABLE LOG_FIRE;

```
ID      LOG_ID      SUB_DIVISION
706     994450      null
705     994154      null
```

TABLE Z_SUB_DIVISION_TYPE;

```
SUB_DIVISION    DISPLAY_NAME 
1               Parallelogram   
2               Circle  
3               Square  
4               Triangle    
5               Tangent 
6               Dot 
7               Line    
8               Rhombus 
9               Trapezium
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the final result you can merge last four columns assuming one column has value and rest are null(sub division columns)

```
SELECT log_id,
       year,
       CASE
        WHEN sub_division IS NULL AND SUB_DIV3 IS NULL AND SUB_DIV4 IS NULL THEN sub_div
        WHEN sub_division IS NULL AND SUB_DIV IS NULL AND SUB_DIV4 IS NULL THEN sub_div3
        WHEN sub_division IS NULL AND SUB_DIV IS NULL AND SUB_DIV3 IS NULL THEN sub_div4
        ELSE
        sub_division
       END as sub_division,
       display_name
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT L.log_id,
                        FC.log_yr                                     AS YEAR,
                        WA.sub_division,
                        AI.sub_division                               AS SUB_DIV,
                        EA.sub_division
                        AS SUB_DIV3,
                        FI.sub_division                               AS SUB_DIV4,
                        (SELECT display_name
                         FROM   z_sub_division_type a
                         WHERE  a.sub_division = WA.sub_division
                         OR     a.sub_division = AI.sub_division
                         OR     a.sub_division = EA.sub_division
                         OR     a.sub_division = FI.sub_division
                         )      AS   DISPLAY_NAME
        FROM   final_calendar FC
               join log L
                 ON To_date (To_char (L.log_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') =
                    FC.cal_date
               left outer join log_water WA
                            ON WA.log_id = L.log_id
               left outer join log_air AI
                            ON AI.log_id = L.log_id
               left outer join log_earth EA
                            ON EA.log_id = L.log_id
               left outer join log_fire FI
                            ON FI.log_id = L.log_id)
```

Edit 1:-This sql works assuming atleast one column has value and rest are null

Edit 2:- You can replace case clause with coalesce

```
coalesce(sub_division,sub_div,sub_div3,sub_div4) as sub_division
```

Comment: What if a values are introduced into the last two columns  ROW1>   990741,  2020,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    5,    ------ROW2>
990742,  2020,    NULL,    NULL,    9,    NULL,     .,,,, Does this sql holds good for it too?

Comment: No You need to add last two columns in `case` clause i.e if first two columns are null then use third column and if third column is null then use fourth column.Add those two rows to sqlfiddle